# Solution for @Html.Raw Controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, the view needs to render the controls as per the data available from the database.

For example, suppose for `ID = 1`, I get `FNAME`, `LNAME` from the database. 
For `ID = 2`, I get `FNAME` only.

In this scenario, I need to display two text boxes for `ID = 1` and only one text box for `ID = 2`.

To achieve this, I am using `@Html.Raw()` and passing the HTML tags as a string.

The issue arises when I have a submit button there. Now, on submitting how can I get the data to the controller, whatever the user has entered, since these controls do not have a model associated with them?

PS - We do not know how many fields database will return. It can be 1, 2 or 50. I have written a for each loop in the controller to create these controls in the string and then passing it to the view.

Comment: Really reconsider your design, playing around with raw tags can become a maintenance nigthmare before long. Why don't you have one model for all records, and just hide the bits your don't have data for? On submit hidden controls can post some default empty data

Comment: But what is required is, if in future new field is added, then they do not need to change the application code - model. Only adding the field into the database will do the work.

Answer (score -1):

Follow below steps

1. While creating textbox, use `name` attribute on them.
2. Put these textboxes or input tags inside a form and that form should
   have action attribute as `controller/action` name.
3. Create an action inside a controller and keep parameters name same
   as the names you provided to textboxes.

```
public class AccountController
{       
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password)
        {
            // here you will get userName & password
            return View();
        }
}
```

HTML Markup

```
 <form action="Account/Login" method="post">
      <input  name="userName"  type="text" />
      <input  name="password"  type="text" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the answer. Somewhat this will resolve the issue partially. But, is there any other workaround for the scenario where the no. of parameters are unknown?

Comment: that depends upon how you code...but I have just shown you this can be done... If my answer helped you then could you please accept it?

Comment: For dynamic no. of parameter, you can use FormCollection as a parameter in action method. Read about FormCollection from here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-formcollection-in-mvc-controller/